# Magento WSDL not Wsi Compliant

Tags: api, wsdl, wsi

I have an issue with the compiled WSDL file not being standard compliant with 3rd party system, SAP.

A base magento install with WS-I compliance turned on in the admin is causing errors within SAP as the wsdl schema is returning nodes in the wrong order.

The message nodes should be grouped together, however as visible here:

> The following nodes separate message blocks, which invalid the strict schema.

```
<portType name="Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortType">...</portType>
<binding name="Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerBinding" type="typens:Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortType">...</binding>
<service name="MagentoService">...</service>
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem? And also has anyone ever needed or know how to reoorder nodes within the combined wsdl file?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure your Magento system is running in WS-I mode **or** I'm not sure you're loading from the WSDL from the correct SOAP URL.  When Magento's running is WS-I mode the `portType` tags render with a `wsdl` namespace prefix.

```
<wsdl:portType name="
```

Your error message indicates a `portType` without a namespace.

```
<portType name="
```

My guess is you're loading the incorrect SOAP URL.  Magento actually has **two** SOAP WSDL end points.  The first, (let's call it simple SOAP), is at

```
http://store.example.com/index.php/api/soap?wsdl=true
```

This was the original SOAP API, and was incompatible with most modern SOAP tool chains. (it **was** consumable via PHP's `SoapClient`)

The second SOAP API, or `V2` API, has its WSDL endpoint at

```
http://store.example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=true
```

This `V2` API was created to provide a SOAP api that was compatible with modern tool chains.  The `V2` API can run in `WS-I` mode, or non-`WS-I` mode.  This is configurable at

```
System -> Configuration -> Magento Core API -> General Settings -> WS-I Compliance
```

For some reason your SAP system is seeing the wrong WSDL.  Figure out why that is and your problems should (may) be solved.

Comment: It was displaying the correct WSDL there are just minor compliance issues relating to order of notes and minimum output messages etc, apparently alot of 3rd party systems who implement Ws-i compliance don't follow all the schemas just the basic ones.

Comment: @alan-storm I have wsdl file. Is there any tool which can convert it to wsi.xml?

Comment: @AmitPatel Just the human mind and hands, as far as I know.  But it might be worth a full fledged question instead of a comment on a answer from four plus years ago.